# Finding an object in a list through a parameter

Tags: java, object, foreach, parameters

Im practicing using ArrayList, so I got this exercise where I need to create a drug farmacy, the farmacy has a list of medicines, and those medicines each contain two drugs, each drug has a boolean allergen.

What I need to do is create a method in the Farmacy class that takes 2 parameters (a person which has allergies and the medicine) the method has to go through the list of medicines and check if there's any allergens in that medicine that match the persons alergic traits.

This is the issue Im having: I need to match up the medicine that is sent through parameter and the medicine that is inside listMedicine, that is all I need,(maybe with aMedicine.getName().equals(oneMedicine.getName())) 
But I tried doing that and it doesnt work.
I can then apply a similar process to the next part of the method.

```
public void checkAllergies(Person onePerson, Medicine aMedicine){

    for(Medicine oneMedicine : listMedicine){



    }
}
```

Thx for the time :)

btw Im using IntelliJ

Comment: Show the code inside the loop (what you tried)

Comment: The data you have provided is insufficient. How to figure out person's allergic traits. To solve this one need object model of Person and Medicine Class, or any other if applicable

Comment: What java are you using? With Java 8 streams were introduced which offer a good and easy filtering function. With java <8 you can still do it easily but with a bit more effort

Comment: Also, what are you looking to achieve with this loop? What would actually happen if the `person` is allergic to the `medicine`? Would you store the `medicine` somewhere? Just print a line like, `person.getName() + " is allergic to " + medicine.getName()`? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak Just edited the question, but yeah basically I just want to show whether the person is allergic or not.

Comment: @Basti Im using Intelli Jetbrains :)

Comment: That is your development environment (like eclipse, android studio or visual studio) but i was asking for the java version your program is built with. The version is independent from the ide.

Comment: @Basti oh yeah, it's Java 8.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @Basti Yeah, but I wasnt supposed to do it like that, I have yet to learn about filtering collections.

Comment: This is how you filter collections. There are a few more functions available from the Collections interface. Instead of removeIf there should exist something that keeps them instead and stuff like that. Check the javadoc of Collections for more info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should filter `Collections` in general

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

/* Java 8+ using streams and predicate (lambda expression)*/
List<Person> personsOlderThan10 = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.age > 10).collect(Collectors.toList());

/* Java 7- using Predicates*/
List<Person> personNamedJohn = new ArrayList<>(persons);
personNamedJohn.removeIf(new Predicate<Person>() {

    @Override
    public boolean test(final Person person) {
        if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().equals("john")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

To figure out if your filter turned out to have any results you can simply check `Collection.isEmpty()`

Just put together a Predicate that represents your filter for medicines/alergies and check if you have a result or not.